# Save more then 200 SMS per contact on 2.3?

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread, sms, samsung-galaxy-gio

I've noticed that my Samsung Galaxy Gio (Android 2.3) saves only 200 SMS per contact. Is there any way to save more?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the messaging app, access `menu` > `settings` > `text message limit`

and set it to a higher number you like.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Did the job :) And I can also turn it off completely.